# Sort-Object ignores substituted switch

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to adapt the sorting order of Sort-Object to a situation.
However, it seems to ignore my variable as the sort order switch -Descending

The following code shows my problem:
I've also tried some variants on the actual substitution, e.g. $($SortOrder) but haven't found a combination that works.

```
$dlist = ("Zeta", "Beta", "Foo", "Alpha","Yada" )  
$sorted1 = $dlist | Sort-Object -Descending  
Write-Host $sorted1  
$sortOrder = "-Descending"  
$sorted2 = $dlist | Sort-Object $sortOrder  
Write-Host $sorted2
```

This produces the following two lines: The first is sorted the second is not

```
Zeta Yada Foo Beta Alpha  
Zeta Beta Foo Alpha Yada
```

What am I failing to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To control the direction of sorting programmatically, use a `[bool]` variable and pass it to the `-Descending` switch; `$true` sorts in descending order, `$false` in ascending order:

```
$descending = $true # Setting this to $false will sort in ascending order.
'Zeta', 'Beta', 'Foo', 'Alpha', 'Yada' | Sort-Object -Descending:$descending
```

Note how `:` rather than the usual space must be used to separate the parameter name from the value in this case (this syntax is generally supported, but otherwise rarely used).<sup>[1]</sup>

---

Alternatively, use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting):

```
$params = @{ Descending = $true }
'Zeta', 'Beta', 'Foo', 'Alpha', 'Yada' | Sort-Object @params
```

---

Both commands yield the desired (descending) order:

```
Zeta
Yada
Foo
Beta
Alpha
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

You cannot pass a switch parameter, such as `-Descending`, as a *string* (variable).

If you do, `Sort-Object` will consider it a *positional argument* that binds to the `-Property` parameter, indicating what property/ies on the input objects to sort by.

If no such property exists, all input objects compare the same (the value they're compared by is `$null` for all of them), with no guaranteed output order.

---

<sup>[1]  The `:` unconditionally tells PowerShell that the next token is the argument *for that parameter*. If spaces were used, PowerShell would consider the next token a *separate positional argument*, given that switch parameters normally do not take arguments (the mere *presence* of a switch parameter *implies* that its value is `$true`).</sup>

Comment: Thanks;  I see a couple things here:
- My experience with other shells, makes me think I can drop strings in, but this is different: arguments to a cmdlet/function are evaluated for what they are.  And this string variable is an object matched against the positional arguments.
- That a switch argument has a bool value.   I don't ever think I've seen an example of that.  One of the first things I tripped over with Sort-Object was that there is no -Ascending switch.  That's the default behavior when nothing is specified.  But is seems that it can also be effected by Descending property false.

Comment: @DaveM: Yes. Even  quoted _literals_ - e.g., `'-Descending'` - aren't treated syntactically. `[switch]` arguments with Boolean values aren't common, because you only need them for _programmatic variations_ in invocations - interactively, you simply either omit or include the switch. And even in the programmatic case it is more common to use a hashtable full of parameter values with splatting.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to do it with Strings:

```
$desc='-descending'

Invoke-Expression ls | sort $desc
```

But the solution above is better